# Where to set -nocursor for an openbox-session on raspbian buster

Tags: raspberry-pi, x11, raspbian, openbox

I'm using openbox-session to run a custom application on a touchscreen on raspian buster.

I want to hide the X cursor effectively using startx -nocursor (or a config option that achieves the same)

Where is the best place to add the -nocursor option (I don't want my change to be overwitten by future package updates to X or related).

**I do not want to use unclutter**

The most likely good place seems to be in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf using a custom xserver-command= line but adding it here doesn't seem to change anything.

What am I missing? Where is the correct and most robust place long term to set the -nocursor option?